# Spark : forEachPartition not working

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to use foreachpartition to save data in my database, but I noticed that this function not working

```
RDD2.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<Object>>() {


            @Override
            public void call(JavaRDD<Object> t) throws Exception {


                t.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<Object>>() {

                    @Override
                    public void call(Iterator<Object> t) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("test");
                    }   }
                );
          }});
```

When I run this example, my my spark program will be blocked in these steps, without showing others RDD or even print test

```
6/05/30 10:18:41 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
16/05/30 10:18:41 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
16/05/30 10:18:41 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, partition 0,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2946 bytes)
16/05/30 10:18:41 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
16/05/30 10:18:41 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: foreachPartition at BrokerSpout.java:265
16/05/30 10:18:41 INFO RecurringTimer: Started timer for BlockGenerator at time 1464596321600
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1464596321500 ms
-------------------------------------------

16/05/30 10:18:41 INFO ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches ArrayBuffer()
16/05/30 10:18:41 INFO ReceiverTracker: Registered receiver for stream 0 from 10.25.30.41:59407
16/05/30 10:18:41 INFO InputInfoTracker: remove old batch metadata: 
16/05/30 10:18:41 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Starting receiver
16/05/30 10:18:41 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Called receiver onStart
16/05/30 10:18:41 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Waiting for receiver to be stopped
16/05/30 10:18:42 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: foreachPartition at BrokerSpout.java:265
16/05/30 10:18:42 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
16/05/30 10:18:42 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 1.0 with 2 tasks
```

As you see in my logging, it says that my spark is Waiting for a receiver to be stopped, but my receiver must not be stopped, if not, what is the purpose of spark streaming if we have to stop the sender.

Comment: Can you verify that you are getting values in foreachRDD()? I had tested your piece of code locally and it perfectly works for me.

Comment: I don't know if there a method that can allow me to print values, but I tried to add System.out.println(t); after call(JavaRDD<Object> t) method , and it shows me MapPartitionsRDD[4] at map at BrokerSpout.java:191, I think my problem is related to foreachPartition

Comment: There is a method print() on DStream, so just call it before context.start();
        context.awaitTermination(); to make sure that values are being populated to it.

Comment: Ah, yes, I tried RDD2. print (); but this doesn't show anything if I run foreachPartition, because this method block everything

Comment: Just comment logic in foreachRDD() for the sake of testing and make sure that data flows in pipeline.

Comment: `Time: 1464596321500 ms` Looks like you're calling `print` somewhere? Also, unless you're running this in local mode, `foreachPartition` will print out in the workers, not the master.

Comment: I run my program in my local, I tired to see what happen using spark GUI and I found that spark show "No tasks have started yet" for my code (print method)

Comment: I changed my machine, and it's work.